# R Replace word in a string

Tags: string, grep, edit, gsub

I have inherited an r project that has a dataframe with truncated text strings. Based on some responses in this forum, I have tried

```
temp$taname2 <- gsub("\bDistr\b", "District", temp$taname2)
```

This did not work. I tried

```
temp$taname2 <- gsub("Distr", "District", temp$taname2)
```

but this resulted in rows already containing the word "District" being changed to "Districtic", "Districtict", or similar. I also tried

```
temp$taname2[grep("\bDistr\b",temp$taname2)] <- "District"
```

but, alas, no luck.

I realise  the answer is ridiculously simple but I haven't been able to work out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace specific characters within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/replace-specific-characters-within-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("\\s+Distr$|^Distr\\s+|\\s+Distr\\s+|^Distr$", " District ", 
     c("ends with Distr", "distr at start", "the word distr in the middle", "distr", "district"),  ignore.case = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of regular expressions as well as the gsub function. I think this question is answered here: [In R, replace text within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-how-do-i-replace-text-within-a-string)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stringi](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/stringi/) package:

```
require(stringi)

mydf<-data.frame(c("\bDistr\b", "\bDistr\b", "\bDistr\b", "\bDistr\b"))
stri_replace_all(mydf[,1], "", fixed="\b")
[1] "Distr" "Distr" "Distr" "Distr"
```