# In R replace punctuation "." within a string

Tags: r, replace, punctuation

I have look into the web and found this webpage [In R, replace text within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-how-do-i-replace-text-within-a-string) to replace a text within in a string.

I tried the same method to replace the punctuation "." into another punctuation "-" but it did not work.

```
 group <- c("12357.", "12575.", "197.18", ".18947")
 gsub(".", "-", group)
```

gives this output

```
 [1] "------" "------" "------" "------"
```

instead of

```
 [1] "12357-" "12575-" "197-18" "-18947"
```

Is there an alternate way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"." in regex langage means "any character". To capture the actual point, you need to escape it, so:

```
gsub("\\.", "-", group)
#[1] "12357-" "12575-" "197-18" "-18947"
```

As mentioned by @akrun in the comments, if you prefer, you can also enclosed it in between brackets, then you don't need to escape it:

```
gsub('[.]', '-', group)
[1] "12357-" "12575-" "197-18" "-18947"
```

Comment: Or `gsub('[.]', '-', group)` or `gsub('.', '-', group, fixed=TRUE)`