# split strings by two different symbols

Tags: r

My rownames in `df` looks like this:

```
hsa-miR-20a-5p_TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA_0;I-A;0;g
```

I would like them to look like this, space separated instead of `_` and `;`

```
hsa-miR-20a-5p TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA 0 I-A 0 g
```

I suppose I could use `gsub`?

Comment: If you, just, want to replace `_` and `;` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-how-do-i-replace-text-within-a-string) and, also, `?regex`. For no regex replacement see, also, `?chartr`; `chartr("_;", "  ", "hsa-miR-20a-5p_TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA_0;I-A;0;g")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `OR` i.e `|` to match multiple delimiters and replace it with space `" "`

```
gsub("_|;", " ", "hsa-miR-20a-5p_TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA_0;I-A;0;g")
#[1] "hsa-miR-20a-5p TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA 0 I-A 0 g"
```

If we need to split it to parts

```
strsplit("hsa-miR-20a-5p_TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA_0;I-A;0;g", "[_;]")[[1]]
#[1] "hsa-miR-20a-5p"          "TAAAGTGCTTATAGTGCAGGTAA" "0"                       "I-A"                     "0"                      
#[6] "g"
```