# select multiple characters before one same character (R)

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

My example as below:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Santiria laevigata Blume f. laevigata", 
                 "Santiria laevigata", 
                 "Santiria laevigata Blume f. glabrifolia (Engl.) H.J.Lam"))

                                                        x
1                   Santiria laevigata Blume f. laevigata
2                                      Santiria laevigata
3 Santiria laevigata Blume f. glabrifolia (Engl.) H.J.Lam
```

I would like to get only `Santiria laevigata` by using `string` to say that I will keep every letters before Blume or in other words, I gonna remove all characters starting from `Blume`.
Any suggestions for me?

Desired output

```
                                     x                  
1                   Santiria laevigata  
2                   Santiria laevigata
3                   Santiria laevigata
```

Comment: Suggested duplicates: [remove/replace specific words or phrases from character strings - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883436/remove-replace-specific-words-or-phrases-from-character-strings-r) and [Replace specific characters within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/replace-specific-characters-within-strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove/replace specific words or phrases from character strings - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883436/remove-replace-specific-words-or-phrases-from-character-strings-r)

Comment: not really my specific thing that I would like to ask

Comment: @Anh Can you check the simple solution i posted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to remove everything from `Blume.*`.

```
df$y <- trimws(sub('Blume.*', '', df$x))
df$y
#[1] "Santiria laevigata" "Santiria laevigata" "Santiria laevigata"
```

Comment: `.*` means that everthing behind Blume?

Comment: thank you it worked well when I apply into `str_remove` function

Comment: Since we are using `'Blume.*'` it means remove everything after Blume. You may also use the same in `str_remove`. `str_remove(df$x, 'Blume.*')`

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `gsub`

```
df$x <- gsub("Blume.+", "", df$x)

                    x
1 Santiria laevigata 
2  Santiria laevigata
3 Santiria laevigata
```

Comment: thank you! It worded well.

Answer (score 1):

you could try changing the df to

```
df <-  c("Santiria laevigata Blume f. laevigata", 
             "Santiria laevigata", 
             "Santiria laevigata Blume f. glabrifolia (Engl.)    H.J.Lam"))
```

and then entering as follows

```
new_df <- substr(df,1,18)
new_df

[1] "Santiria laevigata" "Santiria laevigata" "Santiria laevigata"
```

I don't know how to make it work with

```
data.frame(x = c("abc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(df$x, 1, 2)
[1] "Santiria laevigata" "Santiria laevigata" "Santiria laevigata"
```

Comment: I was using `word`. However, there is only onething that i changed my mind. my data has a lot of species with bad resolution (e.g. `genus HR1` , or `genus G H 1`). Besides, some species having only one characters. So, i dont think `word` is a good choice here

Comment: @Anh Yes, you are right.  I was thinking that you had only similar cases as in the example