# Reformatting R output for SQL Query

Tags: sql, r

I have the following data in c.

```
c <- "'1WK4166', 'ULTQVY8', 'TZDNZX0', '895K3D8', 'RG1NSW9', 'BH73P1', 'WQ9J84'"
```

I am trying to paste the exact output but I don't want the first and last quotiation ("") and want the whole string to be in brackets. as such

```
('1WK4166', 'ULTQVY8', 'TZDNZX0', '895K3D8', 'RG1NSW9', 'BH73P1', 'WQ9J84')
```

The reason I am asking is that I am pasting this into an SQL Query.

Comment: I have no clue what R is but assume that it must have a `replace` or similar. A quick google found this possible duplicate of [**In R, replace text within a string**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-replace-text-within-a-string)

Comment: The opening and closing `"` appear to be the quotes that display in printing the string and I would not expect them to be included in any pasting you do.  Using `paste0("(", c, ")")` will likely work.  I can't be sure, though; your code is not valid R code, so I'm not completely sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are will literally ctrl+c->ctrl+v the query direct from the console to your query window..

```
cat("(",c,")",sep="")
```

..will display the string with brackets and no quotes.