# Convert "2016-08-28T17:12:41.795Z" to "2016-08-28 17:12:41.795"

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame with date and time  column

```
    data    published_at
0   0.0     2015-11-05T12:55:34.685Z
1   0.0     2015-11-05T12:55:44.695Z
2   0.0     2015-11-05T12:56:25.328Z
3   0.0     2015-11-05T12:56:35.333Z
4   0.0     2015-11-05T12:56:45.332Z
```

I wanted to convert into the following format

```
    data    published_at
0   0.0     2015-11-05 12:55:34.685
1   0.0     2015-11-05 12:55:44.695
2   0.0     2015-11-05 12:56:25.328
3   0.0     2015-11-05 12:56:35.333
4   0.0     2015-11-05 12:56:45.332
```

Comment: We just want to remove T and Z ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-replace-text-within-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In R, replace text within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-replace-text-within-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove T and Z if your data frame is called `df`:

```
gsub("T"," ", df$published_at)
gsub("Z","", df$published_at)
```

Note that these are just strings and not dates/timestamps