# How to remove a particular character from a type character

Tags: r, character

In R I have the following problem.

**x="2017-10-03"**

I want to trasform it to

**x="20171003"**

Is it possible?

Comment: `gsub("-", "", x)`?

Comment: Search before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-replace-text-within-a-string

Comment: @MikeVelazco What do you think about it? I think that i didn't it? You're  pro than me to find answers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but as RMonaco says, there is a previous answer that you could have found if you had looked for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are wanting a function similar to a replace() for strings found in many languages like Python and Java, I would use the gsub() function within R.

[Here is an old answer I found that explains it nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-replace-text-within-a-string)

I would imagine your example would look like

```
gsub("-","",x)
```