# Rename df values using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as following :

```
df <- data.frame(month = c("mazda miata 2017", "honda civic 2017"),
                 april = c(.1,.2),
                 may = c(.1,.2)) 

        month april may
1     miata     0.1 0.1
2     civic     0.2 0.2
```

I would like to rename `mazda 3` as `mazda` and `honda civic` as `honda`. How can this be done using dplyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df%>%tidyr::separate(month, c("month","Drop"), " ")%>%select(-Drop)
  month april may
1 mazda   0.1 0.1
2 honda   0.2 0.2
```

Comment: I just realized after your answer on if I have a bigger text and just want that part how to do it. Modified my question. The point being I dont want the first word always.Thank you.

Comment: @SNT You may need to explain more , do you have something , like Honda CRV 1.1 so you want the CRV out put ? Or maybe AUdi Q5 you want Q5 output ?

Comment: I actually have it like `"Marlboro Gold Mainline", "Marlboro Red Mainline", "Marlboro Green Mainline","Marlboro Black Menthol", "Marlboro Black Non-Menthol"` . So I want the names to be `Gold,Red,Green,Black Menthol, Black Non-Menthol`

Comment: @SNT `df%>%tidyr::separate(month, c('Drop','month')," ")%>%select(-Drop)` is this work for you ?

Comment: Wow :) simply Wow  :) Thank you Wen.

Comment: @ Wen I do run into an issue . Both `"Marlboro Black Menthol", "Marlboro Black Non-Menthol"` return as `Black,Black` whereas I would like them be like `"Black Menthol", "Black Non-Menthol"`

Comment: @SNT how about `Marlboro Red Mainline` should it be `Red Mainline`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180071/discussion-between-snt-and-wen).

Comment: @SNT Sorry I can not using the stack chat

Comment: It comes up as Red and I am fine with it

Comment: @SNT how about `df%>%tidyr::separate(month, c('Drop','month')," ",extra = 'merge')%>%select(-Drop)`

Comment: That adds those words but it also add `Mainline` after green and red which I dont want to.The reason being I have two df one of them as `red mainline,green mainline,black menthol and black non-menthol` and then another df I have `red special,green special,black menthol and black non-menthol` . I eventually want to merge these based on `red,green,black menthol,black non-menthol`

Comment: is their a way I can replace `mainline` and `special` by using gsub or something

Comment: @SNT gsub("mainline ", "", yourcolum)

Comment: I did this `gsub("Mainline", "", Secondary_family) %>%` and I get an error `object 'Secondary_family' not found` . Am I doing something wrong with gsub

Comment: @SNT check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/replace-specific-characters-within-strings

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use dplyr?

Easy enough with gsub:

```
df$month <- gsub("honda civic", "honda", df$month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
levels(df$month)[levels(df$month )=="mazda 3"] <- "mazda"
levels(df$month)[levels(df$month )=="honda civic"] <- "honda"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple regular expression with `str_replace`.

In the example below, replace "mazda " and "honda" with anything else you'd like to eliminate. Separate with the OR symbol `|`:

```
 df %>% 
   mutate(month = str_replace(month, "mazda |honda ", "") )

       month april may
1 miata 2017   0.1 0.1
2 civic 2017   0.2 0.2
```