# str_replace_all Error: `replacement` must be a character vector

Tags: r, str-replace, stringr

What is the simplest way to replace patterns in a mixed vector?

```
vec <- c(0, 2500, "A", "B", 2, 3, "M", "+", "\"\"")

library(stringr)

vec <- str_replace_all(vec, c("A" = 0, "B" = 9, "M" = 6, "+" = 0, "\"\"" = 0))

Error: `replacement` must be a character vector
```

Expecting this vector:

[1] "0"    "2500" "0"    "9"    "2"    "3"    "6"    "0"    "0"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace specific characters within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/replace-specific-characters-within-strings)

Comment: `vec <- c(0, 2500, "A", "B", 2, 3, "M")
gsub("A", "0", vec)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use quotationmarks in the replacements as `str_replace_all` expects a string as a replacement:

```
vec <- str_replace_all(vec, c("A" = "0", "B" = "9", "M" = "6", "+" = "0", "\"\"" = "0"))
```

Comment: So obvious! Thank you!